# expecting IDENT, found ''[Under 18]''

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to execute this query, it's work in `phpMyAdmin` but not in my method it give me this Exception

```
expecting IDENT, found ''[Under 18]'': line 1:53: expecting IDENT, found ''[Under 18]''
```

this is my method  :

```
public List<Object[]> getTranche() {
    List<Object[]> list;

    Query req = em.createQuery("SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN age < 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '[Under 18]', SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 18 AND 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '[18-24]', SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 25 AND 34 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '[25-34]' FROM Contrat ");

    return (List<Object[]>) req.getResultList();
}
```

any help please

Comment: I don't know if MySQL is the same in this regard, but in SQL Server you wouldn't wrap your square brackets in single quotes: `AS [Under 18], SUM...` would be fine

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because `'[Under 18]'` **is not a valid alias name**

To solve your problem you have to use a correct alias name, it should be a String for example `AS result` if you want to use space in your name, then you have to use the alias name between two **``** instead like this

```
AS `Under 18`
```

Comment: it is workk there is a method to show the name of colonn with java

Comment: I want to recupere this under18 into variab

Comment: what did you mean @user3529601 i don't get you